# DalekJS: start browser with custom flags

Tags: google-chrome, dalekjs

Is there a way to pass flags / command line switches to the browser being used with DalekJS?

Esentially, I want to use Chrome with some experimental features turned on: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Vanilla CLI startup of custom Chrome looks like:

```
open -a Google\ Chrome --args --enable-experimental-web-platform-features
```

How can I feed those args to Dalek's instance of Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This hasn't made it into the official docs yet, but I recently merged a pull request that allows you exactly that:

See https://github.com/dalekjs/dalek-browser-chrome/pull/8 for more details.
You can add the instructions to your `Dalekfile.json` like so:

```
{
    "browsers": [{
        "chrome": {
            "chromeOptions": {
                "args": ["enable-experimental-web-platform-features", "js-flags=--harmony"]
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: Sweet, that works! Thank you! I saw `chromeOptions` in the source, but no example of how to format it. Perhaps a sample Dalekfile.json with all properties & comments will users getting started.